# Unix script one liner. How can I list files, recurse into sub-dirs and list files WITHOUT an extension

Tags: unix

How can I recuse into a set of directories and list all of the files that DON't have a particular file extension.

E.g.

```
find -name '~(.rs01|rs02)' -type f -exec rm -vf {} \;
```

Also remove them?

Comment: why ask for help when you are just going to use the hack solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grep -v (`man grep` for further information)

`find . -type f` find all regular files

`find . -type f | grep -v ".gif$"` invert match of extension "gif"

`find . -type f | grep -v ".gif$" | xargs rm` and delete it

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -not -name "*.rs01" -and -not -name "*.rs02" -type f -exec rm -vf {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>find !  -name '*.rs01' ! -name '*.rs02' -type f -exec rm -vf {} \;
```

- Use ! to say *not* pattern
- Use -name more than once to specify more than one pattern instead of using |